# GDB error `../gcc-6.2.0/libgfortran/runtime/main.c: No such file or directory`

Tags: gdb, gfortran

I ran my Fortran program with the command **gfortran -g -o vpsc7.out vpsc7.for**. While running the program in GDB step wise I am getting this error.

Starting program: /home/bharat/Desktop/VPSC7c/vpsc7.out

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd972) at vpsc7.for:544
544       END
(gdb) s
_gfortrani_set_args (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd518)
    at ../../../gcc-6.2.0/libgfortran/runtime/main.c:88
88  ../../../gcc-6.2.0/libgfortran/runtime/main.c: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried this before but it is not working now and I don't understand why.

Comment: We need more information. What is your operating system? What is your gdb version? Gfortran version? How did you install gdb and gfortran? Which program did you try to debug? Do you get the error even for a simple Hello world program?

Comment: Is it really an error? Can't you just step over the write or print statement? Can't you step out when the error message is printed? Do you have libgfortran debugging symbols installed?  Do you have libgfortran source installed?